# Simulink BER tool

Tags: matlab, simulink

For BER vs SNR analysis of BPSK, I am using Simulink and BERtool in MATLAB. Shown below is the Simulink model:

[image]

In AWGN component, the parameters are set as below:

[image]

Then I open BERtool -> Monte carlo. Here, Eb/No is selected to be from 0:1:10

It is not changing the Eb/No value in AWGN component for each iteration. What does Eb/No value do exactly in Monte Carlo simulation?

Answer (score 0):

to use the Eb/No selected in the BERTool, you must set the Eb/No field in the AWGN component to `EbNo`, this variable is the `0:1:10` selected in the BERTool.